# Slim Image Cropper symfony2

Tags: jquery, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used Slim Image Cropper with symfony 2, which is responsive and is great for mobiles and desktops , but when it comes to adding it to my symfony project I am a bit stuck.

In the upload there are a few files many being .js files and some php files.

, I want to upload an avatar in may form , i use this in my form

```
<div class="slim" style="border-radius: 50%;"
     data-label="drag your image here"
     data-ratio="1:1"
     data-service="async.php"
     data-size="200,200">
    {{ form_widget (form.imageFile ,{'name':'slim[]', 'attr': {'type': 'file'}} ) }}
</div>
```

after crop i have an input like this :

```
<input type="file" id="imageFile" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,image/bmp" style="margin-bottom: 100%;" aria-required="true"></input>

<input type="hidden" name="imageFile" value="{&quot;server&quot;:null,&quot;meta&quot;:null,&quot;input&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;140929113850-saeed-ahmed-profile-image-full-169.jpg&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;image/jpeg&quot;,&quot;size&quot;:254064,&quot;width&quot;:1600,&quot;height&quot;:900},&quot;output&quot;:{&quot;width&quot;:200,&quot;height&quot;:200,&quot;image&quot;:&quot;data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB......">
```

....: a lot a script that i don't understand

when i click submit button i have this error :
Expected argument of type "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File", "string" given

[error srcean hot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh5pd.png)

How to success parse the Json image object to my input file , so i can upload it !!